# Rails 6 Uniqueness Validation Not Working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-6

I am having problems with the uniqueness validator in Rails 6 when I use the `scope` attribute.

I have a many-to-many relationship between `Product` and `Machine`. My join table is called `ProductMachine`.

In my join table I have the following validation:

```
validates :product_id, uniqueness: { scope: :machine }
```

I am building an import tool that allows me to create the associations for products and machines via a csv import. In this import, I have code that creates new records like this:

```
machine = Machine.first
machine.product_machines.new(product_id: 1234)
machine.product_machines.new(product_id: 1234)
machine.product_machines.new(product_id: 5678)
machine.save!
```

When I call `machine.save!` the new `product_machines` are inserted into the database and the validation does not fail. If I run this same exact code a second time, it fails as expected. I assume this is because the `scope` is making a where clause in the validation which causes the new records to be missed since the are not persisted. How can this be fixed? Here is the documentation for the scoped validation.

https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#uniqueness

Comment: Ah now I see whats happening here. Validations in associated models are not automatically run when you save the parent. You need to use `validates_associated` to trigger the validations of associated models. You could also just do `machine.product_ids=[1, 2, 3, 5, 8]` instead of manually creating the join models.

Comment: @max Thanks for your response. I can verify that the validation is indeed running. The validation also runs correctly when I attempt to execute the exact same code a second time. I believe the problem is that the `scope` attribute triggers a `where` clause that checks for `product_ids` in a query and since my products have not been created yet and are created in a single transaction, they are not validated against the unsaved records which still seems strange. I did try adding `validates_associated` but I still had the same results.

Comment: " and since my products have not been created yet and are created in a single transaction" how can you then have product ids?

Answer (score 0):

You're validating that for any given machine it can only link to the same product once. You're not validating that you can only link one machine to one product.

Normally these sorts of join tables have a `UNIQUE` constraint as well to be sure you don't have duplicate links.

If you're trying to enforce one link and one link only, making that table effectively a one-to-one, you need to constrain differently.

Comment: You are correct by saying that I am trying to validate that a machine can only be linked to a specific product once. How do you suggest I constrain differently?

Comment: If you want one and only one link per machine you need to flip the uniqueness verification: Verify that `machine_id` is unique, no scope. If you want any number of links between machine and product, but only one of each distinct pair, then you should add a `UNIQUE` constraint on that table on `machine_id,product_id` to ensure only one instance of each pair exists.